# Inside Docker Container - python: can't open file './services/web/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create 2x Docker containers:

1. For my WEB API
2. For PostgreSQL DB

I am using `docker-compose` in order to build these containers. Even though I can successfully build them using `docker-compose build` command, whenever I go to inspect the logs using `docker-compose logs -f` command, I am getting the following error message:

```
...
db_1   | 2020-08-19 12:39:07.681 UTC [45] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-19 12:39:07 UTC
db_1   | 2020-08-19 12:39:07.686 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
nlp-influencertextanalysis_web_1 exited with code 2
```

Everything seems fine with db container, but for some reason inside web container Python cannot locate manage.py file. Here is my file structure:

[image]

And here is code for my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/web
    command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./services/web/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user1
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test123
      - POSTGRES_DB=influencer_analysis

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

And here is my code for `Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM python:3.8.1-slim-buster AS training
    # set work directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    # set environment variables
    ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    
    # install system dependencies
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat
    
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    # install NLTK dependencies
    RUN python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"
    
    # copy project
    COPY . /usr/src/app/
    
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app/experiments
    RUN python train.py --data data/HaInstagramPostDetails.xlsx --update 1
```

I should note that I've printed out all fines that are located in `/usr/src/app` when `train.py` is executed with `RUN` command from Docker file, and `manage.py` is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you have changed the working directory at the end of your Docker file.

You can try to give an exact path to your manage.py file or.
Change the working directory in the Docker file at the end that directs to the app directory.

Comment: You are correct. I've forgotten to set back WORKDIR. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem while changing the Working directory. It should have been

`WORKDIR /usr/src/app/web/experiments` based on the folder structure.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for commenting, but that is not it. When I set WORKDIR to be /usr/src/app and copy everything from current project directory level, that does not include web directory. The answer below yours solves my problem. Anyhow, thanks.